# Phalcon install error on Mac "make: *** [phalcon.lo] Error 1"

Tags: php, macos, installation, phalcon

I've been trying for hours to get Phalcon installed on my Mac, but no luck yet.  Everytime i get past one error another seems to pops up.

Right now.  The error I'm getting is this (I've shortened it for readability):

```
/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/phalcon.o
/var/tmp//ccrzKEQO.s:3511:no such instruction: `vmovsd (%r8), %xmm0'
/var/tmp//ccrzKEQO.s:4455:no such instruction: `vmovsd LC29(%rip), %xmm1'
/var/tmp//ccrzKEQO.s:4456:no such instruction: `vmovsd (%rsi), %xmm0'
/var/tmp//ccrzKEQO.s:18294:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm0, %rsi'
/var/tmp//ccrzKEQO.s:18299:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm0, %rsi'
...
:65341:no such instruction: `vucomisd %xmm1, %xmm0'
:65343:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm0, %r15'
:65430:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm0, %r15'
:70978:no such instruction: `vmovsd (%rax), %xmm0'
...
:96648:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm6, %rax'
:96665:no such instruction: `vmovsd (%rdi), %xmm7'
:96666:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm7, %rdi'
:96679:no such instruction: `vmovsd (%rdi), %xmm8'
:96680:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm8, %r14'
:96990:no such instruction: `vmovsd (%rdi), %xmm0'
:96991:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm0, %rdi'
:97156:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sd %eax, %xmm0,%xmm0'
:97158:no such instruction: `vaddsd LC2083(%rip), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:97159:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2si %xmm0, %eax'
:97375:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sd %eax, %xmm0,%xmm0'
:97376:no such instruction: `vaddsd LC2083(%rip), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:97377:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2si %xmm0, %r15d'
:97397:no such instruction: `vmovsd 0(%rbp), %xmm1'
:97399:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm1, %rbp'
:97404:no such instruction: `vmovsd (%rbx), %xmm0'
...
:7283:no such instruction: `vucomisd LC1310(%rip), %xmm0'
:9156:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sdq (%rax), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:9157:no such instruction: `vucomisd LC1310(%rip), %xmm0'
:10956:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sdq (%rax), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:10957:no such instruction: `vucomisd LC2462(%rip), %xmm0'
:11477:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sdq (%rax), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:11478:no such instruction: `vucomisd LC1431(%rip), %xmm0'
:12510:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sdq (%rsi), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:12511:no such instruction: `vucomisd LC1431(%rip), %xmm0'
:17658:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sdq (%rax), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:17659:no such instruction: `vucomisd LC1431(%rip), %xmm0'
:10203:no such instruction: `vmovsd (%rdi), %xmm0'
:10204:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm0, %rax'
:24439:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sdq (%rsi), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:24440:no such instruction: `vucomisd LC1310(%rip), %xmm0'
:24713:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sdq (%rsi), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:24714:no such instruction: `vucomisd LC2462(%rip), %xmm0'
...

:33029:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2si %xmm0, %r12d'
:33128:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sd %r14d, %xmm0,%xmm0'
:33129:no such instruction: `vaddsd LC2083(%rip), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:33130:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2si %xmm0, %r12d'
:33139:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sd %r13d, %xmm0,%xmm0'
:33140:no such instruction: `vaddsd LC2083(%rip), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:33141:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2si %xmm0, %r12d'
:33177:no such instruction: `vcvtsi2sd %r12d, %xmm0,%xmm0'
:33178:no such instruction: `vaddsd LC2083(%rip), %xmm0,%xmm0'
:33179:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2si %xmm0, %r12d'
...
:35607:no such instruction: `vmovsd (%rdi), %xmm0'
:35608:no such instruction: `vcvttsd2siq %xmm0, %rbx'
make: *** [phalcon.lo] Error 1
```

If anybody knows how to fix this error It would be a huge help.  Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1886/can-t-upgrade-to-1-3-x#C6505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I too faced the same problem in the beginning, but I realized that the best method to install Phalcon in mac was this :

1. Go to `Homebrew` and install "Brew"
2. Type this : `brew install phalcon`

And you will have a fresh install of Phalcon all configured!

Comment: Thanks It looks like I got a bit farther than before.  But now I get the error:  checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/php53-phalcon-BBPW/phalcon-cphalcon-00b3853/build/64bits':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details